# why {descendants: true} doesn't work in ContentChildren?

Tags: angular

The purpose of `descendants` configuration property is used to select descendant content children, and without this value, only direct children are selected. Below is my application hierarchy:

```
//the template of the root component

<componentOne>
   <span myCustomDirective></span>         <--------first direct child
   <componentTwo>
      <span myCustomDirective></span>      <--------descendant child
   </componentTwo>
</componentOne>
```

and below is the code of `componentOne`:

```
@Component({
    selector: "componentOne",
    ...
})   
export class FirstComponent {

   @ContentChildren(MyCustomDirective, { descendants: true })
   contentChildren: QueryList<MyCustomDirective>;

   ngAfterContentInit(): void {
       console.log(this.contentChildren);
   }
}
```

and the console result shows that there is only one `MyCustomDirective` which is the first direct child of the component.

But purpose of `{ descendants: true }` is used to select descendant children, which means the second `MyCustomDirective` in `componentTwo` should also be included in `componentOne`'s content children, so why there is only one child not two children?

Answer (score 4):

According to the angular doc https://angular.io/api/core/ContentChildren#description

> Does not retrieve elements or directives that are in other components'
> templates, since a component's template is always a black box to its
> ancestors.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. But if we don't retrieve elements or directives that are in other components' templates, under what circumstances we need to use `{ descendants: true }`, what kind of descendant content children does it refer to? I can only think of that  elements or directives that are in other components' templates can be consideres as descendant content children

Comment: This is the use case for using descendants: true, https://angular.io/api/core/ContentChildren#tab-pane-example

Comment: Nested components with itself.